# How to add a legend to ggplot when aes are constant for stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I tried to plot different smoothings in a single plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y = mpg, col="green")) + 
  geom_point(col='blue') +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", col="red", span=0.1) +
  labs(title = "Fitting Price ~ living space, span=0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75") +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", col="cyan", span=0.25) +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", col="green", span=0.5) +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", col="blue", span=0.75)
```

I want to add a legend to it where it shows the color for each smoothing line. Some answers say to add a color to the `aes`, however I don't have separate `aes` for each `stat_smooth`, and adding `col` to the `aes` of `ggplot` has no effect.

Comment: Why downvote, when there isn't a straightforward solution for it!!! check the answers to see, or suggest an answer if you know a simple one.

Comment: Probably because you've > 3k rep and don't provide a MCVE.

Comment: @jay.sf my code is Minimal complete and verifiable example. Yes, I can change data set and variables with more common ones, but I don't think that's a big issue in this question. I also provided my efforts and said what's the problem of them.... You can check my own answer to better realize the question and expected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `aes` in each `stat_smooth` including only the desired color. This will add legends to the plot. Then you can use `scale_color_identity` to match and rename the colors

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y = mpg, col="green")) + 
  geom_point(col='blue') +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", aes(color = "red"), span=0.1) +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", aes(color = "orange"), span=0.25) +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", aes(color = "yellow"), span=0.5) +
  stat_smooth(method='loess',linetype="dashed", aes(color = "green"), span=0.75) +
  labs(title = "Fitting Price ~ living space, span=0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75") +
  scale_color_identity(name = "Span values",
                          breaks = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green"),
                          labels = c("0.1", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75"),
                          guide = "legend")
```

Read more at [Creating legends when aesthetics are constants in ggplot2](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/legends-constants-for-aesthetics-in-ggplot2/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to add a legend from layers created inside the ggplot call. An alternative is to precompute the smooths and feed them into ggplot in long form.

Here, I define a function to make a fitted loess curve based on input span, then augment `mtcars` with a few of these, then gather into tidy (long) shape, and feed into ggplot:

```
make_loess <- function(span = 0.1) {
  series = paste("Loess with span =", span)
  loess(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, span = span) %>%
    broom::augment() %>%
    select(rowname = .rownames, !!series := .fitted)
}

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  left_join(make_loess(0.25)) %>%
  left_join(make_loess(0.50)) %>%
  left_join(make_loess(0.75)) %>%
  gather(series, val, -c(rowname:carb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt, val, color = series, group = series)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]